# Injecting an SQL to Controller in codeignitor

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, controller

I am trying to inject a SQL with a DATE_FORMAT method and it gives me parsing error. But the query working perfectly in phpmyadmin. Below you can find my code which is my controller

```
public function index() {
  $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT('added_date', "%M") AS Month, SUM(total) FROM tbl_order GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('added_date', "%M")";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $orderData= $query->result_array();
  $data["orderData"] = $orderData;
  var_dump($data);die;
  $this->load->view('admindashboard/index.php',$data);
}
```

I have attached the error message as well[image]

Comment: What's `added_date` is it a colunm from `tbl_order` table?

Comment: Whenever possible paste the error as plain text as well. This helps others with a similar problem find this question and any associated solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to use `'%M'` instead of `"%M"`, because it will split the string by `"`.

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%M') AS Month, 
SUM(total) 
FROM tbl_order 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%M')";
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: If you're using a double-quoted string you need to use single quotes inside it *or* delimit your double quotes like `"...\"quoted\"..."` so that PHP knows your intent.

Answer (score 3):

i suggest to use single quote for whole string and inside it use double quotes.it will solve error i think.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT("added_date", "%M") AS Month, 
SUM(total) FROM tbl_order 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT("added_date", "%M")';
```

Comment: Nop still I got the same error. But D-shah's suggestion working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Your Welcome and Sorry,But Happy Your Error Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If `added_date` is a column you must pay careful attention to the quotes used. In MySQL columns are delimited with backticks, but this is only necessary if they conflict with any [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

The other problem is using both double quotes to define the string and within the string. If you do that you *must* escape the inner ones, like this:

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(added_date, \"%M\") AS Month, SUM(total) FROM tbl_order GROUP BY Month");
```

If you have a syntax highlighting text editor, which is pretty much essential these days, you'd see how the string highlighting stops immediately on what's perceived as a closing quote in your original code. That's a warning you've got a syntax error.

The other fix is to use two different kinds of quotes. MySQL's default mode permits either double or single quotes for string values:

```
 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%M") AS Month, SUM(total) FROM tbl_order GROUP BY Month');
```

In practice it's usually better to use single quoted strings for queries for the singular reason that accidental SQL injection is prevented: `$`-type variables are *not* interpolated in single quote mode.